# No results from solr search q = *:*

Tags: solr, django-haystack

Using solr 4.6.0 the following query returns *no* results:

```
solr/select/?q=*:*
```

But removing the `q` parameter returns *all* results, e.g.:

```
solr/select/
```

The request handler configuration contains the invarient:

```
<str name="q.alt">*:*</str>
```

Since [`q.alt`](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin#q.alt) is supposed to define the query when `q` is not provided, shouldn't the two queries be identical and return results? What are some possible reasons why the first form fails to return documents?

**Additional Background**

I'm using `django-haystack` 2.1.0 to actually connect to solr, the above queries are just the 'simplest failing case' in instances where empty queries are supplied. I've overloaded the haystack `SearchForm` to prevent empty queries returning empty result sets, and this worked with a much older version of solr and haystack 1.4.

Haystack "helpfully" populates `q` with `*:*` if no value is provided. Unfortunately, that's breaking the query as above. I *could* monkey-patch haystack, but I'd rather fix the problem in solr.

Note that queries with a populated (non-empty) `q` parameters work, e.g.

```
solr/select/?q=test
```

This will return results as expected.

Comment: what does a query to solr/select?q=*:* return?

Comment: I think @jro is right, the `/` before the `?` is in the way.

Comment: It returns the same result (as you'd expect - the trailing slash doesn't change where the request is routed to. I'll add a little more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution.

The search handler used [`DisMaxQParserPlugin`](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin) (defType `dismax`):

> The DisMaxQParserPlugin is designed to process simple user entered phrases (without heavy syntax)...

The `*:*` form of `q` was invalid for the DisMax parser, but the `q.alt` provides a fallback that is *"..parsed by default using standard query parsing syntax.."*.

Changing the search handler plugin to [ExtendedDisMax](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtendedDisMax) (defType `edismax`) fixes the problem.